# Loop through an array of objects and count how many boolean are present

Tags: typescript

I have 3 checkbox and I would like to present a warning if the user leaves all the checkbox empty, the user must have at least one checkbox marked.

Template

```
<div *ngFor="let rol of roles">
      <mat-checkbox 
         [checked]="rol.checked"     
         (change)="onCheckboxChange()">
          {{rol.label}}
      </mat-checkbox>
      </div>
```

Class

```
roles = [
    {label: 'administrator', checked: false},
    {label: 'organizer', checked: false},
    {label: 'athlete', checked: false}
  ];

onCheckboxChange() {
    let count = 0;
    this.roles.forEach(key => {
      if (!key.checked) {
        count++;
      }
    });

    if (count === 2) {
      console.log('add a rol please');
    }
  }
```

I have also tried this:

```
onCheckboxChange() {
    let count = 0;
    for (const rol of this.roles) {
      if (rol.checked === false) {
        count++;
      }
    }

    console.log(count);
  }
```

Right now, nothing happens when all of the checkbox is unchecked. My goal is to verify if at least one checkbox is marked, otherwise give a warning to the user. Also, tell the user which rol was selected.

Comment: Did you try debugging this? Adding a breakpoint and check your values?

Comment: @MCMatan Yes, `count` is always 0 or 2. I don't understand what is happening.

Comment: Because you are never changing the underlying array data. You are using `one-way` binding. So as the user checks the boxes, it is *not* updating the underlying array data and the values keep their original value of false. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be that you are checking the value of the array in your component, but you have no code that is changing the value in the array when the checkbox is checked.

Try using two-way binding instead:

```
<div *ngFor="let rol of roles">
      <input type="checkbox" 
         [(ngModel)]="rol.checked"     
         (change)="onCheckboxChange()">
          {{rol.label}}
 </div>
```

(I changed this to a normal checkbox instead of material design, but it should work the same way.)

By using `[(ngModel)]` (two-way binding), as the user clicks on the checkbox the underlying `checked` property in the array will change to match.

You can also simplify the code in the component as follows:

```
  onCheckboxChange() {
    // Returns false unless at least one box is checked.
    let result = this.roles.map(r => r.checked).some(value => value === true)
    if (!result) {
      console.log('add a rol please');
    }
  }
```

The `map` operation maps from the array of objects to an array of the single property you are interested in (the `checked` property), resulting in an array of Boolean values. The `some` method tests whether at least one element matches the criteria. See this for more information on `some`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

I have a stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-firumq

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about the existence of `some`, great function. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

with your code you need to check if the *value is equal to 3 instead of 2*  .

```
if (count === 3) {
  console.log('add a rol please');
}
```

Updated function using `map` operator

```
let count = 0;

 this.roles.map((data) => {
     if (data.checked) {
         count++;
     }
})

 if (!count) {
    console.log('add a rol please');

 }
```